# Interpretation the law of total expectation

Tags: expected-value, joint-distribution, conditional-expectation

For a function of two RVs we have: $$ E[g(X,Y)] = E[\underbrace {E\{ g(X,Y)|Y\} }_{It\space is\space a \space function \space of\space  Y}] = E[h(Y)] $$. 
For each $Y=y$, the inner expectation is the mean of marginal density $p_X(x)$ evaluated by $g(x,y)$.

$$E(g(x,Y = y)) = \int_x {g(x,Y = y){p_X}(x)dx}  = h(y)$$
Is my interpretation correct?

If it is, then in approximating the joint expectation by samples we can say:

> We first sample from marginal $p_Y(y)$ and then draw x samples from the marginal $p_X(x)$ (figure below).

[image]

Comment: The interpretation and the generation are both incorrect: $X$ is conditional on $Y=y$.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for comment. If $y$ is fixed, then the inner expectation is over $X$ only. Is it correct? So as a result why we cannot say "the inner expectation is the mean of marginal density $p_X(x)$"?

Comment: I think you want to say that: 1-The inner expectation is the mean of conditional density $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$. And 2- We choose a fixed $y$ and then draw sample from the conditional density$ p_{X|Y}(x|Y=y)$?

Comment: Could you please make an answer and explain the correct interpretation and how we can relate it to sample generation?